# Generator raised StopIteration when locateOnScreen

Tags: python, pyautogui

I'm creating a script to find image on the screen, my code is like this:

```
import pyautogui

image = pyautogui.locateOnScreen('my-image.png')
print(image)
```

The image is a print screen, so the scale of the image is the same.

When the image is not on the screen, my script is printing `None`, but when the image is on the screen, it's returning an error like this:

```
$ python index.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Projects\project\lib\site-packages\pyscreeze\__init__.py", line 234, in _locateAll_python
    raise StopIteration()
StopIteration

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "index.py", line 3, in <module>
    image= pyautogui.locateOnScreen('my-image.png')
  File "C:\Projects\project\lib\site-packages\pyscreeze\__init__.py", line 266, in locateOnScreen
    retVal = locate(image, screenshotIm, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Projects\project\lib\site-packages\pyscreeze\__init__.py", line 250, in locate
    points = tuple(locateAll(needleImage, haystackImage, **kwargs))
RuntimeError: generator raised StopIteration
```

What it's wrong in my code? I'm using Windows 10 x64.

Answer (score 3):

It's not a problem with your code. The `pyscreeze` maintainers need to update their code to use `return` instead of `raise StopIteration()` to end their generators, as PEP 479 has been [enabled for all code](https://docs.python.org/3.7/whatsnew/3.7.html#changes-in-python-behavior) in Python 3.7, changing the behavior of `StopIteration` in a generator.

Comment: Wow, BTW, what can I do to get the image position? Or maybe the only way is migrate to use python 2?